# Why won't this DAX formula work?

Tags: excel, powerpivot, dax

I'm currently using a DAX formula to try and remove numbers from a string. The string is the first half of a postcode. I've therefore typed the following formulae

```
=if(Istext(mid([Postcode District],1,1)),(left([postcode district],2)),(left([postcode district],1)))
```

what this SHOULD do is see if the second character is text and return 2 letters if it is, one if it isn't.

For example, input `CA1` should return `CA` whilst `B22` should return `B`

This simply isn't doing that, and I'm not sure why. all that is being returned is the first two letters whether the second letter is text OR numeric.

Comment: sorry pnuts, could you explain this fully in an answer format for me please? Not sure what you mean.

Comment: I don't think DAX recognises CODE as an operation?

Comment: No need to apoligise pnuts :) I'm happy just to have suggestions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ended up using `=SUBSTITUTE(substitute(SUBSTITUTE( SUBSTITUTE( SUBSTITUTE( SUBSTITUTE( SUBSTITUTE( SUBSTITUTE( SUBSTITUTE( SUBSTITUTE([Postcode District],"1"," "),"2"," "), "3"," "),"4"," "),"5"," "), "6"," "),"7"," "),"8"," "),"9"," "),0,"")` 
(as its DAX it'll accept this - it's too many nested functions for standard XL)

As it's quite an ugly formulae, I'll be trying other people's answers too, to see if there's a more elegant solution :)

Answer (score 1):

The MID function takes a string as an argument and will always return a string (even if it looks like a number), so your IsText is always TRUE.

Try this

```
=if(IsNumber(mid([Postcode District],1,1)*1),(left([postcode district],1)),(left([postcode district],2)))
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon, i'll give that a try :). Just as a note, as it's a DAX formula not a standard Excel one, the locations are one to the right (i.e. 1=0, 2=1, 3=2 etc.)

Comment: Thanks, I'll edit my response to take account of that in case anyone else is looking for the same answer.